# Getting "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" after updating constraint in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I've got a UITableViewController, with a custom view, with some subviews and controls inside, in the header of the table. Each one of these subviews are a custom subview (use a custom subview to draw corner radius with IBInspectable) and each have constraints for top, bottom, leading and trailing space (all set to 8) as well as for height (set to 60, 80 or 100, depending of each subview).

One of these subviews constraints can be modified programmatically in run time depending of user interaction. To do that, I create this two methods:

```
- (void)showSearchTypeTermField:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.searchTypeHeightConstraint.identifier = @"Height 100";

    [self.searchTypeHeightConstraint setConstant:100.0];

    if (animated) {
        [self.tableView.tableHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [self.tableView.tableHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    } else {
        [self.tableView.tableHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
    }

    self.searchTypeTermField.hidden = NO;
    self.searchTypeTermField.text = @"";

    [self.tableView.tableHeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingExpandedSize];
}

- (void)hideSearchTypeTermField:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.searchTypeHeightConstraint.identifier = @"Height 60";

    [self.tableView.tableHeaderView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

    [self.searchTypeHeightConstraint setConstant:60.0];

    if (animated) {
        [self.tableView.tableHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [self.tableView.tableHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    } else {
        [self.tableView.tableHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
    }

    self.searchTypeTermField.hidden = YES;

    [self.tableView.tableHeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
}
```

Because all of these subviews are in the table header view, every time I change the constraint, header should expand or compress depending of the case, thats why I use `self.tableView.tableHeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`.

The problem is I'm getting this error, when I call `[self hideSearchTypeTermField:NO]` the first time on `viewdidLoad` despite that visually everything seems fine:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf504e0 V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bea3ab0(60)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf51760 V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf50690(60)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf53390 'Height 60' V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf518e0(60)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf53ec0 V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf535a0(80)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf54a80 V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf54180(80)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf54eb0 V:|-(8)-[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bea3ab0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bea3a10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf54f40 V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bea3ab0]-(8)-[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf50690]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf54f70 V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf50690]-(8)-[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf518e0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf55090 V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf518e0]-(8)-[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf535a0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf550f0 V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf54180]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bea3a10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf55180 V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf535a0]-(8)-[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf54180]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7c149fc0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7bea3a10(428)]>"
)
```

I'm really lost with this issue. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try adding the heights for the `SeachFormBackgroundView` instances (60 + 60 + 60 + 80 + 80 + 8 * 6 = 388 and their separators you'll see that they aren't equal to the parent UIView height (428). That's why you get this message.

You have to either adjust the constraints so that they add up to the parent view height, or resize the parent so that it's size matches the child constraints.

You don't need all of the constraints you have right now. Since you're setting a specific height to all of the subviews and spacing constraints, you only need to anchor them to the top or to the bottom of the superview.

*Edit:*

You don't need both of these constraints: `V:|-(8)-[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bea3ab0]` and `V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf54180]-(8)-|`. The first one anchors your subviews to the top of the superview, and the scond one anchors them to the bottom of your superview. Remove one of them (I'd expect the bottom one) and the views will fall in place without throwing any AutoLayout exceptions.

Comment: In storyboard I have 60 + 60 + 100 + 80 + 80 + 8*6 = 428. The 100 height subview is the one i change programmatically, then is what it shows in the console.

Comment: When the view is shrinked, what's supposed to happen to the other views? If they need to go up, you should modify to bottom spacing constraint (8) to accomodate the new `SeachFormBackgroundView` height constraint. So if you're substracting 20 from the one that's 100 in the beginning, you need to add it to one of the spacing constraints, or to one of the other `SeachFormBackgroundView` views. So that means that the bottom vertical spacing constraint would need to be 8 + 20 = 28

Comment: But, by doing that, there will be a 28 points gap between the two subviews, right? I want to keep that distance to 8 points.

Comment: There wouldn't be a gap between subviews because you're chaging the constraint between the lowest subview and the parent view

Comment: An even better solution would be to completely remove the bottom costraint `V:[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bf54180]-(8)-| ` (or the top one `V:|-(8)-[SeachFormBackgroundView:0x7bea3ab0]`, depending on where you want the views to stay). That would make the layout to auto adjust when changing the height of one of the subviews

Comment: You should set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on the parent view (the one which says 428 height) to false - the constraints say it has to be 428, but after your change it can't be that height anymore.

Comment: @TheEye from what I understand that's not a problem, he wants the superview to stay at 428. He only wants the subviews to resize.

Comment: @marosoaie Well, removing the bottom constraint from the last view makes the message to disappear. But them the superview height doesn't fit the new height.

Comment: @TheEye Doing that causes a crash
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
`

Comment: You need to make an IBOutlet for the superview height constraint and change that when the total height of the subviews change.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the header view the table view reads its size and sets a constraint for that height. Updating the constraints on the header view itself don't cause a reevaluation of that height. You should remove the header view, update its constraints, lay it out and then add the header view again.

Comment: I don't change the header view, only one of his subviews, the use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` in order to the header view to adapt his height to the change.

Comment: Exactly, you change the header view height. Remove it from the table view while you do that.

Comment: Just made this  
````UIView *headerView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
    
    [headerView 

systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
````
but still get the same error

Comment: `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` isn't doing what you think. It's returning a size that the view wants to be, but it isn't actually resizing the view. You should use `layoutIfNeeded` instead.